# Divide a window into two in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I wanted to make two frames for the scientific calculator project I was tasked to code; one part would be the calculator and the other part would show the history of operations that were typed in by the user, here is what I have tried so far:

```
import math
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.configure(background="lightgray")
root.resizable(width=True,height=True)
root.geometry("1042x521+0+0")

calc = Frame().grid()
history = Frame().grid()
```

Comment: You can't divide the window. Instead, use 2 frames whose sizes are half of the window each

Comment: The ttk::PanedWindow widget accepts 2 widgets and handles resizing using a sizing bar. You can use the `weight` option when adding the child widgets to get the default sizes equal (eg `panedwindow.add(child, weight=1)` for each child). If you set the widget state to disabled, then it will be fixed to that size for each child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will divide the window into 2 equally sized frames.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

calc = Frame(root, bg = "red")
calc.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nesw")
history = Frame(root, bg = "green")
history.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nesw")
```

`grid_columnconfigure` tells tkinter to make each column take an equal width of the window, and `grid_rowconfigure` tells it to make row 0 take up the entire height of the window. Then you need to use `sticky = "nesw"` to make the frames expand to fill the space.